# Keyboard of iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

What do you think why I receive this error when I type something on my simulator keyboard:
`Making temp file at '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards/images/tmp.kR7XTkAW' failed: 'No such file or directory' (2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting the simulator's content and settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and reseting the simulator under "iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings..." worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, there's something wrong with you installation. An image required for the keyboard (whatever it may be) has been removed. The simplest solution would be to uninstall Xcode, and then re-install. However, you may want to try to restart the iOS simulator (cmd-Q to quit), and re-run your application.